# Display the selected choice of a dynamically generated 'selectizeInput' widget based on the selected choice of previous widget

Tags: r, input, shiny, reactive, shinyapps

I am trying to build a Shiny app that generates rows with multiple selectInput or selectizeInput widgets when a user presses the "+" button, and that removes such rows when he presses the "-" button. The image below show what I have achieved since now:

How my shiny app looks right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTRYM.jpg

My problem is that I can't find a way to show the widgets in the new row with the same selected values of the widget in the previous row. In fact, the user may want to change just values of some inputs and don't touch the values of the others.

Referring to the image above, let's suppose that for the first test an user has selected "Amikacin" as antibiotics and "5" as AMR. The second test is always with "Amikacin" but he got the AMR value of 10. The new inputs, right after pressing the "+" button, must display immediately "Amikacin" and "5", and after that the user will just change the "5" of the second row in a "10".

Here is the code I have used:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

###= UI
ui <- fluidPage(

br(),

useShinyjs(),

  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12,
           actionButton(inputId = "add_amr_test",
                        label = icon(name = "plus",
                                     lib = "font-awesome")),
           actionButton(inputId = "remove_amr_test",
                        label = icon(name = "minus",
                                     lib = "font-awesome")),
           div(style = "display: inline-block;
                        padding: 0px 10px;",
               h5("Add or remove an antimicrobial resistance test")),
           tags$div(id = "amr_test_placeholder")
    )
  ),

br()

)

###= SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Antibiotics_name <- c("", "Amikacin", "Ampicillin", "Tetracycline")

  observe({

    toggleState(id = "remove_amr_test",
                condition = input$add_amr_test > input$remove_amr_test)

  })

  amr_test_values <- reactiveValues(val = 0)

  ###= Add ui
  observeEvent(input$add_amr_test, {

    amr_test_divId <- length(amr_test_values$val) + 1

    insertUI(
      selector = "#amr_test_placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = tags$div(
        id = amr_test_divId,
        fluidRow(

          br(),

          column(width = 3,
                 selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("drug_",
                                                 input$add_amr_test - input$remove_amr_test),
                                label = h5(paste0("Antibiotic ",
                                                  input$add_amr_test - input$remove_amr_test)),
                                choices = Antibiotics_name,
                                selected = "")
          ),
          column(width = 1,
                 selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("rescom_",
                                                 input$add_amr_test - input$remove_amr_test),
                                label = h5(paste0("AMR ",
                                                  input$add_amr_test - input$remove_amr_test)),
                                choices = c("",
                                            seq(from = 1,
                                                to = 100,
                                                by = 1)),
                                selected = "")
          )
        )
      )
    )

    amr_test_values$val <- c(amr_test_values$val,
                             amr_test_divId)

  })

  ###= Remove ui
  observeEvent(input$remove_amr_test, {

    removeUI(

      selector = paste0('#', amr_test_values$val[length(amr_test_values$val)])

    )

    amr_test_values$val <- amr_test_values$val[-length(amr_test_values$val)]

  })

}



###= RUN APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Finally, here is an image with the expected results obtained after the user presses the "+" button to generate the second row of widgets.

Example of expected result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL3Ex.jpg

One last question: once every widget from the user has a specific value, which is the best way to store all these values inside a dataframe?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thought you might be interested in this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571196/how-to-add-a-button-that-removes-input-rows

Comment: Thank you so much Eli, I will try to understand if this situation fits my case! You're very kind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below for your first question:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

###= UI
ui <- fluidPage(

br(),

useShinyjs(),

  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12,
           actionButton(inputId = "add_amr_test",
                        label = icon(name = "plus",
                                     lib = "font-awesome")),
           actionButton(inputId = "remove_amr_test",
                        label = icon(name = "minus",
                                     lib = "font-awesome")),
           div(style = "display: inline-block;
                        padding: 0px 10px;",
               h5("Add or remove an antimicrobial resistance test")),
           tags$div(id = "amr_test_placeholder")
    )
  ),

br()

)

###= SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Antibiotics_name <- c("", "Amikacin", "Ampicillin", "Tetracycline")

  observe({

    toggleState(id = "remove_amr_test",
                condition = input$add_amr_test > input$remove_amr_test)

  })

  amr_test_values <- reactiveValues(val = 0)

  ###= Add ui
  observeEvent(input$add_amr_test, {

    amr_test_divId <- length(amr_test_values$val) + 1

    # Simplified input_number here and code to obtain previous values if they exist
    input_number <- input$add_amr_test - input$remove_amr_test
    if (!is.null(eval(parse(text = paste0("input$drug_", input_number - 1))))) {
        drug_value = eval(parse(text = paste0("input$drug_", input_number - 1)))
    } else {
        drug_value = ""
    }
    if (!is.null(eval(parse(text = paste0("input$rescom_", input_number - 1))))) {
        rescom_value = eval(parse(text = paste0("input$rescom_", input_number - 1)))
    } else {
        rescom_value = ""
    }

    insertUI(
      selector = "#amr_test_placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = tags$div(
        id = amr_test_divId,
        fluidRow(

          br(),

          column(width = 3,
                 selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("drug_",
                                                 input_number),
                                label = h5(paste0("Antibiotic ",
                                                  input_number)),
                                choices = Antibiotics_name,
                                selected = drug_value)
          ),
          column(width = 1,
                 selectizeInput(inputId = paste0("rescom_",
                                                 input_number),
                                label = h5(paste0("AMR ",
                                                  input_number)),
                                choices = c("",
                                            seq(from = 1,
                                                to = 100,
                                                by = 1)),
                                selected = rescom_value)
          )
        )
      )
    )

    amr_test_values$val <- c(amr_test_values$val,
                             amr_test_divId)

  })

  ###= Remove ui
  observeEvent(input$remove_amr_test, {

    removeUI(

      selector = paste0('#', amr_test_values$val[length(amr_test_values$val)])

    )

    amr_test_values$val <- amr_test_values$val[-length(amr_test_values$val)]

  })

}



###= RUN APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Eli Berkow, thank you so much for your prompt response and for your simple, elegant and also very smart solution, it totally works fine. Hope this would be helpful also for others. About my second question, I then stored the data in a dataframe by applying `sapply` to every variable for which I obtained the input in this way: `input[[paste0("variable_", i)]]`.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. That sounds like a clever way of storing the data. I looked at that question for a bit but it seemed quite complicated to try and keep track of the inputs and all updates to them.

Comment: Eli, in the same way that you created the different inputIds, what would be the best way to customise the new widgets with some css? For example, for the selectizeInputs of the "drug_i" I tried to add (on the top), this code:
`tags$style(paste0("#animal_species_", input_number(), " {font-size:1px; width:200px; height:5px;}"))`, but it doesn't seem to work. I can't specify a general tag for every widget because they should be different. Thanks again.

Comment: This is quite a different question and may be worth creating separately on SO. Please give me the exact requirements. Must drug be different from rescom? Individual drug/rescom?

Comment: Yes Eli, but I managed to find a solution. By wrapping every column (with multiple dynamic input for ONE variable) inside a div(), I changed the style of all the selectizeInput widget just for that div() and it worked. Thanks a lot for your interest and your prompt responses!

Comment: Great!. Good luck

Comment: [Eli Berkow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4819909/eli-berkow) I have added a new question related to this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413465/reactive-deletion-of-dynamically-generated-widgets-updating-their-insertion-orde). Thanks in advance for your availability.

Comment: Hey Eli, any suggestion on how to modify the code to make the first row automatically displayed when a user opens the form?

Comment: The first row with empty values or filled in?

Comment: You could add `observeEvent(input$add_amr_test, {...}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)` but I need to know exactly what you want after that. You could also add the first row in your ui. Should it be able to be removed as well or not?

Comment: Eli basically when the application starts there should just be the first empty row (for example what happens if you press the first time the "+" button). This row is empty as the others but once filled everything should be copied again as what happens in your answer. Not sure if there should be the need to delete it, maybe not. What do you think? Should I create another question in which you would be able to answer better?

Comment: Did you try the ignoreNULL = FALSE above?

Comment: Just tried, the first row is displayed well but the count starts on 0 and the "remove" button doesn't remove the rows anymore. Should I also modify something in the other observer?

Comment: also edit `condition = input$add_amr_test >= input$remove_amr_test` (>=) and edit `input_number <- input$add_amr_test - input$remove_amr_test + 1`

Comment: Also the remove button just wouldn't allow removing the first row - it would remove others. Play around with the > and >= for this if you want the first row to not be removed.

Comment: Eli, sorry for my previous comment, I made a mistake by putting the amr_div ID in quotes ("amr_test_divId") and hence the remove button didn't work anymore. Your solution is brilliant. Thank you very much.