# How to add a button that removes input rows?

Tags: r, shiny

I have some code to program a small shiny app for which I need to add input rows and, if needed, delete them again. I have figured out how to add inputs, however I can't figure out how to delete them.

Here is a MWE of my code. There is no output since I cannot share the excel sheet behind the code from which the output is generated. However, it should suffice for simply helping me find the correct code to remove the added rows with full input (except the first row):

```
library(shiny)

GeographyList <- c("Africa","Asia Pacific","Europe","Global", "United States","Latin America & Caribbean")
RegionList <- c("Emerging", 
                "Developed")
ClassList <- c("1",
               "2",
               "3")


# Define UI for app that draws a plot ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("inputwidgets"),

      actionButton("number", 
                   "Add Row"),

      # Input: Click to update the Output
      actionButton("update", "Update View"),

      # Output: Plot ----
      h4("Allocation"),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  )


# Define server logic required to call the functions required ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Get new input by clicking Add Row
  observeEvent(input$number, {
    output$inputwidgets = renderUI({
      input_list <- lapply(1:input$number, function(i) {
        # for each dynamically generated input, give a different name
        fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 selectInput(paste0("Geography", i),
                             label = paste0("Geography", i),
                             choices = GeographyList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = NA)
          ),
          column(3,
                 selectInput(paste0("Region", i),
                             label = paste0("Region", i),
                             choices = RegionList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = NA)
          ),
          column(4,
                 selectInput(paste0("Class", i),
                             label = paste0("Class", i),
                             choices = ClassList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = NA)
          ),
          column(3, 

                 # Input: Specify the amount ----
                 numericInput(paste0("amount",i), label="Amount", 0)
          ))
      })
      do.call(tagList, input_list)
    })

  })


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$update == 0)
      return()

    isolate(input$number)
    isolate(input$amount)
    slices <- c(input$amount1,input$amount2,input$amount3,input$amount4)
    pie(slices)
  })


}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Appreciate any tips since I am very new to shiny! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has such an example using removeUI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356463/display-the-selected-choice-of-a-dynamically-generated-selectizeinput-widget-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build your `lapply` loop based on a reactiveValue which is triggered by your add button and a delete button:

**1. Edit: using `sapply` in  `output$distPlot` according to `lapply` rows**

**2. Edit: using existing input values**

```r
library(shiny)

GeographyList <- c("Africa","Asia Pacific","Europe","Global", "United States","Latin America & Caribbean")
RegionList <- c("Emerging",
                "Developed")
ClassList <- c("1",
               "2",
               "3")

# Define UI for app that draws a plot ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("inputwidgets"),

            actionButton("number",
                         "Add Row"),
            actionButton("delete_number",
                         "Delete Row"),


            # Input: Click to update the Output
            actionButton("update", "Update View"),

            # Output: Plot ----
            h4("Allocation"),
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)


# Define server logic required to call the functions required ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    reac <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(c(input$number,input$delete_number), {
        # you need to add 1 to not start with 0
        add <- input$number+1
        # restriction for delete_number > number
        delete <- if(input$delete_number > input$number) add else input$delete_number
        calc <- add - delete
        reac$calc <- if(calc > 0) 1:calc else 1
    })
    # Get new input by clicking Add Row
    observe({
        req(reac$calc)
        output$inputwidgets = renderUI({
            input_list <- lapply(reac$calc, function(i) {
                Geography <- input[[paste0("Geography",i)]]
                Region <- input[[paste0("Region",i)]]
                Class <- input[[paste0("Class",i)]]
                amount <- input[[paste0("amount",i)]]

                # for each dynamically generated input, give a different name
                fluidRow(
                    column(2,
                           selectInput(paste0("Geography", i),
                                       label = paste0("Geography", i),
                                       choices = GeographyList,
                                       multiple = FALSE,
                                       selected = if(!is.null(Geography)) Geography
                           )
                    ),
                    column(3,
                           selectInput(paste0("Region", i),
                                       label = paste0("Region", i),
                                       choices = RegionList,
                                       multiple = FALSE,
                                       selected = if(!is.null(Region)) Region
                           )
                    ),
                    column(4,
                           selectInput(paste0("Class", i),
                                       label = paste0("Class", i),
                                       choices = ClassList,
                                       multiple = FALSE,
                                       selected = if(!is.null(Class)) Class
                           )
                    ),
                    column(3,

                           # Input: Specify the amount ----
                           numericInput(
                               paste0("amount",i),
                               label="Amount",
                               value = if(!is.null(amount)) amount else 0
                           )
                    ))
            })
            do.call(tagList, input_list)
        })

    })


    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        req(reac$calc, input$update)

        slices <- sapply(reac$calc, function(i) {
            c(input[[paste0("amount",i)]])
        })

        pie(slices)
    })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work, however, when I remove a row the input still seems to be running in the background! I have a plot as output that does not update when removing the row - do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does your plot now also depends on `reac$calc` or whatever name you specified for your reactive value?

Comment: This is the code for my plot:

`
 output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$update == 0)
      return()
    
    input$number
    input$amount
    slices <- c(input$amount1,input$amount2,input$amount3,input$amount4)
    pie(slices)
  })
`

Not sure how to adapt this?

Comment: I am also unsure how to get a better solution for displaying the plot than using amount1 amount2 and so on in case there are more than four inputs! Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: sorry haven't  realised you posted your plot snippet as well. You can use `sapply` for this the same way you are using lapply, here to obtain a vector for `slice`. I'll update my code

Comment: Thanks for the update! However, now the plot is not displayed at all. Any idea why?

Comment: typo, had to be `input$update` not `input$amount` of course

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you! One last question, how do I prevent shiny to delete the input of the previous rows if I delete one row? Right now everytime I delete a row, all other rows are reset to 0

Comment: I edited the code again, now first checking whether an input already exists in the loop

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for your help, highly appreciate it!!